# Django return select_related() filter as JSON

Tags: django, json

I'm trying to return an object and it's relations as JSON.
It works fine if I do this:

```
plant = Plant.objects.get(slug=kwargs['slug'])
return HttpResponse(serializers.serialize("json", [plant]), content_type='application/json')
```

But whenI try to `select_related()`, no worky:

```
plant = Plant.objects.select_related().filter(slug=kwargs['slug'])
return HttpResponse(serializers.serialize("json", [plant]), content_type='application/json')
```

Is there some way to make Django stop being lazy and and build the object?
I know I could go ahead and render to a template and then display the output as JSON, but that seems a bit of a kludge.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, I'm going to answer my question. Don't know if it will work for all cases.

The solution for me is:

```
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(plant.get_fields()), content_type='application/json')
```

This works because I've defined a fairly elaborate `get_fields()` method to handle some concatenating of OneToMany and ManyToMany relationships.

Hope it helps someone else!

Answer (score 1):

I really don't think it has anything to do with `select_related()`

when you do this `plant = [plant]` 
you are putting your `QuerySet` inside a list so in the serializers/base.py  when it iterates over the list it finds a `QuerySet` instead of individual objects that's why the error `'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_meta`

But for the case

```
plant = Plant.objects.get(slug=kwargs['slug'])
return HttpResponse(serializers.serialize("json", [plant]), content_type='application/json')
```

while iterating on the list `[plant]` it gets an object which has the `_meta.local_fields` so it works for you

I would imagine it will work for you if you just do this

```
plant = Plant.objects.select_related().filter(slug=kwargs['slug'])
return HttpResponse(serializers.serialize("json", plant), content_type='application/json')
```

I am just passing `QuerySet` to the serializer and not a list which contains a `QuerySet`.

I don't know if this is what you were asking.

Comment: This is right, thanks. I actually ended up using a method to display the stuff I wanted (it's cleaner).

Answer (score 0):

Well that is because you did not select anything.

Try this:

```
plant = Plant.objects.filter(slug=kwargs['slug']).select_related()
```

Comment: No, it's getting the data, but it's just the queryset. The error is `'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_meta`

Comment: And if I use plant[0] I get the plant object, but no related fields.